# Non-static IP: script to alert change

Tags: dns, ip

I have a server at home with basic DSL.  I registered a domain name (at GoDaddy) and can login remotely just fine.  However, this requires the input of the IP address and a static IP would be prohibitively expensive.  I haven't found a good dynamic service.  Instead, it seems that my IP address doesn't change very often--maybe once a month--and so it's just as easy for me to update the GoDaddy domain information.  However, I would like to receive an alert from my server when this change happens.  Here's the script that I wrote to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

oldipinfo=""

while [ 1 ]
do
  sleep 3600
  ipinfo=`lynx -dump checkip.dyndns.org`
  if [ ipinfo != oldipinfo ]
  then
    echo "New IP for server $(ipinfo)" | mail -s "NEW IP!" myaddress@gmail.com
    echo $ipinfo >> ipinfo.out
    oldipinfo=ipinfo
  fi
done
```

This actually e-mails me (and updates the file) every hour, so I've done something wrong?

Thanks for your help!

JV

Answer (score 0):

You never read the oldipinfo from the file you cache it in, so your script always has `oldipinfo` set to an empty string, meaning that `"" != x.x.x.x` will always be true.

You should have

```
oldipinfo=`cat ipinfo.txt`
```